# C toLowerCase Function won't work - Access violation

Tags: c, access-violation, lowercase

I have a simple function which takes an array of characters as an argument, and converts all the characters to lower case. However, I get a weird access violation error. Here's the code:

```
void toLower(char *rec)
{
 int i=0;
 while (rec[i]!='\0')
 {
  if (rec[i]>='A' && rec[i]<='Z') 
               rec[i]='a'+rec[i]-'A';  //this is where I get an error - assigning the
                                       //the value to rec[i] is the problem
  i++;
 }
}
```

Can you tell me what's my mistake?
Thanks

Comment: If this isn't homework, there is a C++ standard library function, `std::tolower` in `<cctype>` that does just this.

Comment: @James McNellis: But tolower only works on a single character.

Comment: Is this array of characters or string? If this is array, you need array length as additional parameter.

Comment: No, this is not a homework, I'm just exercising my C++ which got rusty a bit... :)

@Kenny: I use this: toLower(rec); where rec is also passed to a function from which I call toLower like this:

int palindrome(char *rec)
{
...

@Alex: this is an array, but in the end I have a null terminating string, so it's not a problem.

And btw, the function crashes in its first iteration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a comment you say that you pass in a literal string to the function, like this:

```
palindrome("In girum imus nocte et consumimur igni")
```

where `palindrome` passes its argument to `toLower`. This won't work because string literals are read-only and you are trying to modify it. Instead, you can use:

```
char str[] = "In girum imus nocte et consumimur igni";
palindrome(str);
```

Or you can have `palindrome` copy its argument into an array and call `toLower` on that.

Comment: Thanks! Solved it! 
However, before trying 

char str[] = "In girum imus nocte et consumimur igni";

I tried

char *str = "In girum imus nocte et consumimur igni";

And it didn't work. Why? What's the difference?

Comment: `char *str ="..."` is a pointer that receives the address of the read-only string literal, which can't be modified. `char str[]="..."` is an array, so it can be modified.

Answer (score 6):

You're working too hard :)

```
#include <algorithm> //For std::transform
#include <cctype> //For std::tolower
#include <cstring> //For std::strlen

void toLower(char *rec)
{
    std::transform(rec, rec + std::strlen(rec), rec, std::tolower);
}
```

Comment: True, but won't solve the problem here (which is probably a bad argument being passed in).

Comment: @interjay: Yes, but if he does this he can eliminate this function as the likely cause of the problem. Standard library functions don't make mistakes.

Comment: Thanks, but the point is that I want to exercise my C a little :)

Comment: @misaizdaleka: Then you should tag your question C, not C++.

Comment: @ misaizdaleka
Exercise your C skills by doing something novel :) Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Because this is what they ask on a job interview! :)

Comment: Your post doesn't answer OP's question

Comment: @qrdl: Yes, but the question has been edited since I posted this answer.

Answer (score 6):

Are you passing in (even indirectly) a string literal?  If so, then it may be loaded in unwriteable memory; you'll need to make changes on a copy.

That your function prototype takes a `char *` rather than a `const char *` suggests that you've probably not done this, but I thought I`d throw it out.

Comment: OK, in the main program I do this:

printf ("%d \n", palindrome("In girum imus nocte et consumimur igni"));

then, palindrome(char *rec) calls toLower(char *rec), passing the string which I passed in the first place.

Comment: Looks like this is a problem -- trying to modify a string literal.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you didn't pass in a valid buffer.  But don't write this yourself; use something like [strlwr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y889wzfw%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).